# concat and sum multiindex pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have two pandas series

series1

```
Company      Product      Price
ABC          Apple        1234
             Orange       123
BCD          Apple        123
PCT          Pineapple    434
             Beef         884
```

series2

```
Company      Product      Price
BCD          Orange       751
PCT          Pineapple    632
             Orange       165
```

I would like to concat the two series into a series 3

```
Company      Product      Price
ABC          Apple        1234
             Orange       123
BCD          Apple        123
             Orange       751
PCT          Pineapple    1066
             Orange       165
             Beef         884
```

I have tried to use

```
series3 = pd.concat([series1,series2]).sum(level=1)
```

However, it cannot produce what I want. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
series3 = pd.concat([df,df1]).groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()

# Output: 


Company   Product     Price
ABC        Apple      1234
           Orange     123
BCD        Apple      123
           Orange     751
PCT        Beef       884
           Orange     165
           Pineapple  1066
```